# Echap acceleo syntax element

Tags: eclipse, syntax, escaping, acceleo

I have an acceleo project in eclipse, and i want to generate with it an other acceleo file.
The problems I encounter is that I can't manage to find how I can escape acceleo syntax element.

For exemple, if I want to generate :
"[module toAcceleo('http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/5.0.0/UML')]", and consider it as simple String instead of acceleo syntax elements.

I tried to surrond it with [[ ]], or escape [ with / or , but I can't remove the 'The invocation isn't terminated' error'. I don't find anything in the doc...

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT :I found the solution on this page : https://wiki.eclipse.org/Acceleo/FAQ

Just need to escape the right and left brackets like this : [ '[' /] and [ ']' /].

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).